# Sum of Date Range and Text String in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
=SUMIF(Masterlist_data!G:G,"SS7",Masterlist_data!I:I)

=SUMIF(Masterlist_data!G:G,"SS8",Masterlist_data!I:I)
```

this is my formula to compute the items in here
[image: here]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Masterlist_data!I:I,--(TEXT(Masterlist_data!B:B,"MMMM")=Book_monthly!C1))
```

and this is my formula to compute the total by month

i try many things how can i search the items by month
i try to combine those two but it cant be help hahahaha

Comment: What is your actualy problem, cannot really tell from your information displayed here?

Comment: the items is computed by ITEM CODE only like SS7,SS8 and many more

Comment: i like to compute it by ITEM CODE and MONth

Comment: Why dun you try pivot table? I only see one month here, how to compute...

Comment: i have the masterlist of the month in the other sheet thats the computation of the items

Comment: if you want to sum by two different aggregate conditions, you should use SUMIFS instead of SUMIF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really show how your master list look like, however I try with the following outcome using `sumifs` and add a helper column for the month,, accept if help :)

Helper Formula (Column F)

```
=MONTH(C3)
```

Main Formula(July)

```
=SUMIFS($D$3:$D$9,$A$3:$A$9,$H3,$B$3:$B$9,$I3,$F$3:$F$9,7)
```

Main Formula(Aug)

```
=SUMIFS($D$3:$D$9,$A$3:$A$9,$H3,$B$3:$B$9,$I3,$F$3:$F$9,8)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, comparison is always my favourite part :)